# Infinite loop - iteration, the function returns true

Tags: loops, go, infinite

I've question. I need to make a program running in the background. The program is to collect and save data in my database.

I started to do so:

```
func main() {
   for {
      doAll()
   }
}
```

And that retrieves data from all addresses at one time ("go" function):

```
func doAll() {
   rows, err := MySQL.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM `settings`")
   checkError(err)
   defer rows.Close()
   for rows.Next() {
      c := make(chan bool)

      var http string

      err = rows.Scan(&http )
      checkError(err)

      go doOne(http)
      <- c
   }
}
```

And that retrieves data from one web site.

```
func doOne() {
   // some code
   c <- true
}
```

My question is whether iterations of the "doAll" function will be in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the iterations of `doAll` will be in order, because the `c` channel is unbuffered. That means in your `for rows.Next()` loop, the read from `c` will wait until `doOne` writes to the channel.

You can make this code simpler by removing the channel and executing `doOne` synchronously (that is: just call it as a function). The code refactored in this way has exactly the same semantics.